# postgresql open connection and execute more then one command

Tags: postgresql, dart, dart-async

I want to do the following two insert operations using the postgresql driver for dart. 
The code below works!

```
INSERT INTO posts(
            title, description, posted_at, last_edited, "user", 
            editor, up_votes, down_votes, flag, links_to)
    VALUES ('test title', 'test description', now(), now(), 'dartUser', 'dartUser', 
            0, 0, 'healthy', 'http://google.com');


INSERT INTO atatched_tags(
            post_id, tag)
    VALUES (currval('posts_post_id_seq'), 'testTag');
```

The second insert should only be done if an optional parameter is given to the dart method.
The code I have right now looks like this.

```
  addPost(Map post_values, [Map tag_values]){
    Connection conn;
    connect(uri)
    .then((_conn){
      conn = _conn;
    })
    .then((_){
      conn.execute('''insert into posts(title, description, posted_at, last_edited, "user", editor, up_votes, down_votes, flag, links_to)
                                  values(@title, @description, now(), now(), @user, @editor, @upVotes, @downVotes, @flag, @links_to)''', post_values)
      .catchError((err){
        print('Execute error in addPost: $err');
    })
    .then((_){
      if(tag_values != null){
        _addTagToPost(conn, tag_values);
      }
    })
    .whenComplete(() => conn.close());
    })
    .catchError((err) => print('Error in addPost: $err'));
  }

  _addTagToPost(Connection conn, Map values) {
    print('trying to add tag to attached tags');
    conn.execute("insert into atatched_tags values(currval('posts_post_id_seq'), @tag)", values)
    .catchError((err){
      print('Execute error in addTagToPost: $err');
    });
  }
```

I run the method as follows.

```
dbUtil.addPost({'title': 'Sample title', 
    'description': 'This is a description for a sample post', 
    'user': 'dartUser', 'editor': 'dartUser', 'upVotes': 0,
    'downVotes': 0, 'flag': 'healthy', 'links_to': 
    'http://google.com'}, {'tag':'testTag'});
```

`dbUtil` is an instance of the class where the two methods above reside.

The code does not throw any errors. But even though it writes to the console `trying to add tag to attached tags` the second insert operation is not executed (no rows are added to the table). The first works as expected.

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: If somebody wants to add mulitple tags in the `_addTagToPost` function then this code might be helpfull.
Edit2: The code below is **incorrect** I leave it, but check the comments in the accepted answer.

```
  Future _addTagToPost(Connection conn, List<Map> values) {
    var completer = new Completer();
    values.forEach((value){
      conn.execute("insert into attached_tags values(currval('posts_post_id_seq'), @tag)", value)
          .catchError((err){
            print('Execute error in addTagToPost: $err');
          });
    });
    return completer.future;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `return` here

```
return _addTagToPost(conn, tag_values);
```

and

```
Future _addTagToPost(Connection conn, Map values) {
  print('trying to add tag to attached tags');
  return conn.execute(
      "insert into atatched_tags values(currval('posts_post_id_seq'),
      @tag)", values)
  .catchError((err){
    print('Execute error in addTagToPost: $err');
  });
}
```

to keep the async operations connected. Otherwise the connection is closed before `_addTagToPost()` is finished which results in not completing this SQL statement.

Update to the edit in the question. This could also be done like

```
Future _addTagToPost(Connection conn, List<Map> values) {
  return Future.wait(values.map((value){
    return conn.execute("insert into attached_tags values(currval('posts_post_id_seq'), @tag)", value)
        .catchError((err){
          print('Execute error in addTagToPost: $err');
        });
  }));
}
```

or

```
Future _addTagToPost(Connection conn, List<Map> values) =>
    Future.wait(values.map((value) => conn
        .execute(
            "insert into attached_tags values(currval('posts_post_id_seq'), @tag)",
            value)
        .catchError((err) => print('Execute error in addTagToPost: $err'))));
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. The code looks nicer. Are there also speed gains?

Comment: Same speed. But now I looked closer at your code and saw that it doesn't do what it is (or I think it is) intended for. Because you don't use the future returned from `conn.execute()` the completer doesn't complete when all commands are done but already when all commands are enqueued in the Dart event queue (but not yet even started). `Future.wait` waits for all futures to be completed and then completes the future it returns.

Comment: You are right. Interestingly enough my code still works. It seems that `execute` is able to complete the task before the connection to the data base is closed.